# Opencart vqmod error Cannot redeclare modification()

Tags: opencart2.x, vqmod

I have opencart Version 2.0.3.1 and installed vqmod-2.5.1-opencart.
I was installing a extension by extension installer by upload the zip file of extension.

I got the error:

> "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare modification() (previously declared in
>   /home/username/public_html/mydomain.com/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_startup.php:49)
>   in /home/username/public_html/mydomain.com/system/startup.php on line
>   65"

And I couldn't finish my installer. Anyone had this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because your new module is trying to modify a file which is already modified by some other module.

In other words, this new module of your's is conflicting with some existing module n your store. Contact new module's developer to help you install this module. He will make changes accordingly.